# CentOSの仮想デスクトップ環境でcronからFirefoxを起動したい

Tags: centos, firefox, cron

CentOS 6.8の仮想デスクトップ環境でcronからFirefoxを立ち上げたいのですが、成功しているかどうかわからないため、お教えいただければと思います。

まずcron自体は正常に動作しており、試しにファイルを作るコマンドを登録したところ、動作しておりました。

そこで、Firefox を開くコマンドを登録したのですが、実行時間になってもデスクトップ上でFirefoxが立ち上がりません。

- コンソール上で以下のコマンドを実行するとブラウザが開きます。

  ```
  firefox -p kaikaimon -url https://example.com
  ```
- cronに以下の通り設定するとブラウザが開きません。

  ```
  30 22 * * * firefox -p kaikaimon -url https://example.com
  ```

これは裏でブラウザを開いているということなのでしょうか？

ログを見る限り、動作しているように見受けられました。
お教えいただけますと幸いです。

Comment: firefox は X Window System のアプリケーションですので、環境変数 `DISPLAY` を設定するか、もしくはオプションスイッチで表示先を指定する必要があります。例えば、`firefox --display ':0.0'` などとします。ただ、仮想デスクトップ環境とのことですので、`':0.0'` の部分(ディスプレイ番号とスクリーン番号)を変更する必要があるかもしれません。コマンドライン上で `echo $DISPLAY` を実行して、表示される文字列を指定してみて下さい。

Comment: マルチポスト　https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q13177964838

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/88058

Answer (score 3):

環境変数DISPLAYも設定してfirefoxを起動してみてください。

`30 22 * * * export DISPLAY=:0 && firefox ...`

https://askubuntu.com/questions/780337/how-to-open-an-url-in-firefox-via-cron-cron-jobs-scheduling

Comment: ありがとうございます！！無事開くことができました！！